# How to combine HttpServletRequest + @RestController

Tags: java, spring

I have developed my current Webapp in Java/Spring MVC. I have exposed my REST services by using the @RestController annotation on a class, looking something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class ConcreteCompanyController implements CompanyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public JsonCompany get(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
       //omitted
    }

}
```

I am also using Google libs that require me to write a class looking kind of like this(taken from googles sample):

```
public class CalendarAppEngineSample extends AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet {

  static final String APP_NAME = "Google Calendar Data API Sample Web Client";

  static final String GWT_MODULE_NAME = "calendar";

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("<!doctype html><html><head>");
    writer.println("<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">");
    writer.println("<title>" + APP_NAME + "</title>");
    writer.println(
        "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" + GWT_MODULE_NAME + ".css\">");
    writer.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" " + "src=\""
        + GWT_MODULE_NAME + "/" + GWT_MODULE_NAME + ".nocache.js\"></script>");
    writer.println("</head><body>");
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    writer.println("<div class=\"header\"><b>" + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "</b> | "
        + "<a href=\"" + userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURL().toString())
        + "\">Log out</a> | "
        + "<a href=\"http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse"
        + "/calendar-appengine-sample?repo=samples\">See source code for "
        + "this sample</a></div>");
    writer.println("<div id=\"main\"/>");
    writer.println("</body></html>");
  }

  @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    return Utils.getRedirectUri(req);
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
    return Utils.newFlow();
  }
}
```

I don't know how to combine these so that both will be available as rest services. I guess I might have to do something in web.xml, but what?

Edit:

Just to clarify. I have several RestControllers in my project and I do not want to change them. I want to be able to add a file like the CalendarAppEngineSample and make sure that the doGet method is exposed as a rest service.

Answer (score 6):

You just need include it in the list of method parameters:

```
public JsonCompany get(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam("name") String name)  {           
       //omitted
}
```

it will be automatically filled and you can use it in `get` method.

**UPD** According to your last comment, if you need to extend the class `AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet` keeping its signature, then do this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class ConcreteCompanyController extends AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
         String name = request.getParameter("name");
        // omitted code
   }
}
```

If it is not what you are looking for, then I do not understand what you need.

Comment: That won't work, I need to extend the "AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet". I don't want to combine them in the same method, I want to be able to have both types of rest services in the same webapp.

Comment: In this case it is unclear what you are asking. If you need extend `AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet` - so just do it, and all neded params will be filled automatically by Spring.

Comment: Are you saying that if I put that sample code from Google in a file in my project, then Spring will automatically find the doGet method and expose it as a rest service?