# How can I prevent the automatic decoding of RequestParam Strings in a Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, http

I have an HTTP GET request controller endpoint where I take in a fileName as a query param and pass that on to another service.  For this request the param the filename could include any sort of special characters and I would like to keep these values encoded when passing them on.  2 Characters that have been causing issues are spaces (%20) and +(%2B).

How can I keep these characters encoded in the request params.

So far I have tried using the @RequestParam annotation as well as retrieving the params via HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues(String) but both return the decoded values as spaces.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: You can inject the `HttpServletRequest` to the endpoint method as parameter (see, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41590670/4216641) by [Andremoniy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1479414/andremoniy)). From there, you should have access to the encoded values.

Comment: I'm able to get the value fine however it's always decoded in the request and @RequestParam variable for example a request in a request like http://localhost:8080/my-service?fileName=Tran%2Bsf%20er.pdf the fileName value is "Tran sf er.pdf" when i'm wanting it to either be "Tran+sf er.pdf" or the original encoded value "Tran%2Bsf%20er.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could get the actual value passed in by using the HttpServletRequest.getQueryString() method.  Parsing this query string I was able to get the un-decoded version of the fileName being passed in. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are automatically decoded by the servlet API. You should be able to re-encode them -

```
encodedValue = URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: This almost works however every space is being encoded as a +.  I need to be able to keep the exact encoding that is passed into the service because I'm dealing with filenames.  For example I need fileName="My+new PDF.pdf" to be the value "My%2Bnew %20PDF.pdf".